# Convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} x \cos (x^6)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I feel that $\int_0^{\infty} x \cos (x^6) dx$ is convergent using the regular first year definition of an integral. I have been trying to convince a university professor of this, but according to him I am wrong. Perhaps I am?

My idea is that you do a u-substitution and get an value proportional to $\int_0^{\infty} \cos(x^3) dx$ and this is convergent because it alternates faster and faster. So, the area of each hump is alternating and absolutely smaller. From this every sequence is Cauchy.

Thoughts?

Edit: It appears that I was right. Let me curb some naysayers by recalling that $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)dx := \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^n f(x)dx$ and this is well defined for all $n>0$. Hence, we are just taking a limit. The question is if this limit exists.

Comment: You are right. Your explanation as to why $\int_0^\infty\cos(x^3)\,dx$ converges might need more rigor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the OP, the intuition is good, but details are missing. The oscillations are indeed more and more rapid, but one has to verify that the positive and negative parts do almost cancel.

The integrand is well-behaved on $[0,1]$ so we can work with $\int_1^\infty x\cos(x^6)\,dx$. Rewrite this as
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^4}\cdot x^5\cos(x^6)\,dx,$$
and integrate by parts, letting $u=\frac{1}{x^4}$ and $dv=x^5\cos(x^6)\,dx$. Then we have $du=-\frac{4}{x^5}\,dx$ and we can take $v=\frac{1}{6}\sin(x^6)$.  We end up needing to show that the integral
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x^6)}{x^5}\,dx$$
converges, which is clear since $\sin(x^6)$ is bounded.

**Remark:** If we want to be more formal, we can let $I(B)$ be the integral from $0$ to $B$. Then $I(B)$ is the integral from $0$ to $1$ plus the integral from $1$ to $B$. Essentially the same argument shows that $\lim_{B\to\infty} I(B)$ exists.

Comment: You also need $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^4} \cos(x^6)$ to exist, but this is the same argument. =)

Comment: That the "first" part given by integration by parts behaves well is a more basic fact than the nice behaviour of the second part, so I did not mention it. For both I needed to avoid $0$, which is why the integration is from $1$ on.

Comment: Ah, so the integral is indeed convergent?

Comment: @imranfat:  Yes, it is convergent. The integration by parts method not only shows that, it (particularly if iterated) lets us give good estimates for the integral, and for the tail $\int_B^\infty$ as a function of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [improper integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) and is defined as
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_0^Mx\cos(x^6)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Although $\limsup\limits_{x\to\infty}x\cos(x^6)=\infty$ and $\liminf\limits_{x\to\infty}x\cos(x^6)=-\infty$, the oscillation of the integrand becomes so fast, that the limit $(1)$ exists.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^Mx\cos(x^6)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac16\int_0^{M^6}x^{-2/3}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac16\int_0^{\pi/2}x^{-2/3}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac16\int_{\pi/2}^{M^6}x^{-2/3}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x^{1/3}+\frac16\int_{\pi/2}^{M^6}x^{-2/3}\,\mathrm{d}\sin(x)\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}x^{1/3}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&+\frac16\left(M^{-4}\sin\left(M^6\right)-(\pi/2)^{-2/3}\right)
+\frac19\int_{\pi/2}^{M^6}x^{-5/3}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit as $M\to\infty$ yields,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x\cos(x^6)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}x^{1/3}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{dx}\\
&+\frac19\int_{\pi/2}^\infty x^{-5/3}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
-\frac16(\pi/2)^{-2/3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
and these integrals converge.

---

Using a bit of contour integration, we can get a closed form for the preceding integral:
$$
\frac{\sqrt3}{12}\Gamma\left(\frac13\right)\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider this integration as sum of fragments where $cos(x^6)$ crosses zero two times. you know that the
 $$\int_{a_n}^{b_n} x \cos (x^6) dx<\int_{a_n}^{b_n} |x| dx<\Sigma (c_n \frac{2\pi}{n^6})$$

where $c_n$ is maximum value of x in this period. The order of $c_n$ is $O(n^1)$

$x$ grows with power one but the fragment length shrinks with power 6. So this integrate is smaller than a convergent sum of an exponential series.

Comment: @David Mitra Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

- As far as convergence is concerned, see [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).
- As for evaluation, use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula) in conjunction with the definition of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) to arrive at $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty f\big(x^n\big)~dx=f\bigg(\frac\pi{2n}\bigg)\cdot\Gamma\bigg(1+\frac1n\bigg)$, where $f\in\big\{\cos,\sin\big\}$ and $n>1$.